# how to detect a Key Sequence in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom-events, keyboard-events, userscripts

i am writing an userscript that post in a forum each time a shortcut sequence is executed [ ctrl + enter ], but the function that i wrote excecutes both keydowns as separate events, and not a single sequence.

i checked the related questions, but none of them really exlained how to configure the function to handle the sequence.

this is the code that i wrote :

```
let boutton_toast = document.querySelector('.btn-poster-msg');

function toast(e){
    if (e.ctrlKey && e.key=="Enter"){
       boutton_toast.click();
    }
}
document.addEventListener("keydown", toast)
```

i feel like the answer is really obvious but i can't guess it.

#### edit :

i used fordat's method and it worked, here's the final code :

```
let button_toast = document.querySelector('.btn-poster-msg');
        let pressedKeys = [];

        function bothKeysPressed() {
            if (pressedKeys.includes('Enter') && pressedKeys.includes('Control')) {
                button_toast.click();
            }
        }

        document.addEventListener('keydown', () => {
            pressedKeys.push(event.key)
            bothKeysPressed();
        })

        document.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
            pressedKeys = pressedKeys.filter(key => key !== event.key)
        })
```

Comment: Delete the `{` in `if` statement: `if (e.ctrlKey && e.key=="Enter") boutton_toast.click();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try creating a list (or any data structure really) that stores the variables, something like this:

```
pressedKeys = [];

function bothKeysPressed() {
    if (pressedKeys.includes('Enter') && pressedKeys.includes('Control')) {
      console.log("Enter and Control are pressed!");
    }
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', () => {
   pressedKeys.push(event.key)
   bothKeysPressed();
})

document.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
   pressedKeys = pressedKeys.filter(key => key !== event.key)
})
```

Then just include an additional function in your "keydown" listener that checks for the two keys you need.

Comment: thanks !  it's less simple than expected but this trick will do the work for me

Comment: @hopepill I amended my answer some for clarity, works on my Mac at least

Comment: tested it and it works on my pc too,   exactly the effect that i wanted

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I follow.

this certainly works:

```js
let div = document.querySelector('.test');
let counter = document.querySelector('#counter');
var i=0;
function toast(e){      
    if (!e.repeat && e.ctrlKey && e.key=="Enter"){ // check for e.repeat otherwise if user holds down both keys it calls the function repeatedly 
        //console.log(e)
        let randomColor = '#' + Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);        
        div.style.backgroundColor=randomColor;
        i+=1;
        counter.innerText=i;
    }
}
document.addEventListener("keydown", toast);
```

```html
<div style="width: 10em; height: 4em; background-color: lightblue" class="test"></div>
<div id="counter">0<div>
```

You're missing a closing "}" in your attached code.

Please attach a minimal reproducible example.